# Fresh installed Visual Studio NuGet package manager cannot import Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm trying to create an asp.net core 2.0 web api project with visual studio enterprise edition(fresh installed) and NuGet Package Manager fails at build phase of the project.

**Here is the error message on visual studio**

[image]

**Result of dotnet restore**

[image]

Any ideas about this problem?

.csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="DataTransObj" />
    <Folder Include="Json" />
    <Folder Include="LogDepot" />
    <Folder Include="FileDepot\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.7.1-dev-00950" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.1-dev-00790" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

obj/...nuget.g.targets file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\netstandard.library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\netstandard.library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets')" />
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\build\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.NETCore.App.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\build\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.NETCore.App.targets')" />
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets\2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets\2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.targets')" />
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets')" />
    <Import Project="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.all\2.0.7\build\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.all\2.0.7\build\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Check the contents of C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.all\2.0.7\build\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.targets? if possible, post the data here.

Comment: There is no content in that file. Its empty.

Comment: Clear the contents of sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder and do a restore.

Answer (score 0):

> Fresh installed Visual Studio NuGet package manager cannot import Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package

The default asp.net core 2.0 web api project template contains some nuget packages, which will import some `.targets` file. According to the error message:

> "The imported project file ...Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.targets, cold
>   not be loaded. Root element is missing"

It seems the imported `.target` file is damaged in the `NuGetFallbackFolder` folder. Since it is a fall back folder, to resolve this issue, you can delete this package in that folder. Then when you create a new project, you will find Visual Studio will load that package from global packages folder `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`. Or you can copy this package from global folder to the `NuGetFallbackFolder`.

Hope this helps.